# Does Mathematica know about trig identities?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I am calculating some geometry via two different ways in Mathematica. One uses a known trig identity the other doesn't.

We define angles of two right-angle triangles.

```
angFar = ArcTan[hiod/dist];
angNear = ArcTan[hiod/(dist - depth)];
```

Then calculate their difference

```
disp = FullSimplify[angNear - angFar]
```

This gives

```
-ArcTan[hiod/dist] + ArcTan[hiod/(-depth + dist)]
```

We then do the same recognising that `beta-alpha == ArcTan[(Tan[beta] - Tan[alpha])/(1 + Tan[beta]*Tan[alpha])]`

```
trigID = ArcTan[(Tan[beta] - Tan[alpha])/(1 + Tan[beta]*Tan[alpha])]
```

Substituting

```
dispViaTrigID = 
 FullSimplify[trigID /. {alpha -> angFar, beta -> angNear}]
```

Gives

```
ArcTan[(depth hiod)/(-depth dist + dist^2 + hiod^2)]
```

How do I show with Mathematica that `disp==dispViaTrigID`?

**Additional Info requested**

Diagram of the geometry

[image]

All variables are Real and greater than zero. Angles are 0<angle<Pi/2.

Comment: `{disp, dispViaTrigID} /. {hiod -> 2., depth -> 2., dist -> 1.}` indicates they are not equivalent (which has to do with branch cut discontinuities -- see docs for `ArcTan`). You might need to use appropriate hypotheses. Or be satisfied with `FullSimplify[Tan[disp] == Tan[dispViaTrigID]]`.

Comment: Include a labeled graphic that shows the geometry that you are dealing with.

Comment: MichaelE2 and Bob Hanlon: Thanks, I think the diagram and edits will clarify.

Comment: `Tan[disp] // FullSimplify` gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks @yarchik, that does work. What is the reason Mathematica can only do it that way?

Comment: As @MichaelE2 said, the two expressions are not equivalent for the whole definition domain. Therefore, some transformations involving inverse functions are not even attempted.